# Show/Hide Pop-Up with JS, form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form, when the user click on send..the fields are sent to AJAX and then to php function.
After this, open a pop-up/div.

I'm trying to do, when user click somewhere on the site, this div is hide.
But isn't working, any ideas?

HTML Form:

```
<form id="contactForm">
                <select id="contactFormSelect">
                  <option value="General" selected>General</option>
                  <option value="Support">Support</option>
                  <option value="Suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                  <option value="Jobs">Jobs</option>
                  <option value="Press">Press</option>
                  <option value="Founder">Founder</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input id="contactForm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br />
                <input id="contactForm" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"><br />
                <input id="contactForm" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br />
                <textarea id="write" name="textarea" placeholder="Write here"></textarea><br />
                <input id="submitForm" type="button" value="SEND" onclick="contactRequest(this);">
            </form>
```

HTML Pop-up/Div:

```
<div id="contactSent">
<div id="backgroundOpacity"></div>
<div class="contactSent">
    <div id="contactSentFirst">
        Thank you!
    </div>
    <div id="contactSentSecond">
        Your message has been successfully sent. We will contact you very soon!
    </div>
</div>
<div id="buttonOK">
    Ok
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function contactRequest(elem)
{   
var postData = $('#contactForm').serialize();
    postData += "&textarea="+$('#write').val();
    postData += "&selectedOption="+$('#contactFormSelect').val();;

if($(elem).parent().children('#contactForm').val() != ''){      
    $.ajax(
    {
          url: "/newcontact/pedido-contato/",
          type: "POST",
          data: postData
    });

}
$('#contactSent').show();
}


$('body').click(function(){
$('#contactSent').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up div element you're talking about sounds like the bootstrap modal element. Perhaps you should take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals.  Modals are really easy to implement and they give documentation for it on the site.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your backgroundOpacity element is on top of the body tag. Try to assign the event to it.

```
$('#backgroundOpacity').click(function(){
    $('#contactSent').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But still doesnt close :S

Comment: are you clicking on it? does it cover the whole background? also, check the console for errors when you click

Comment: yes, i have tested with alert too and doesnt work. i tested with #backgroundOpacity, #buttonOK, #contactSent, .contactSent ...nothing work :(

Comment: I assume you are adding the event on $(document).ready() function